# How to install SDL2 library in Fedora 20

Tags: linux, sdl-2, fedora20

There is a question about the SDL package (SDL 1.2) in Fedora in StackOverflow. But I can't found any about `SDL2` in Fedora, and I am having troubles to install the `SDL2` package.

I search and the command to install `SDL2` in Fedora is:

> sudo yum install SDL2*

But still having problems to found the `#include "SDL2/SDL.h".`.

After looking in usr/include/, I wasn't able to found the SDL.h...

So how can I install `SDL2` package and make it work in Fedora 20 distro?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Make Sure to have SDL2 and development headers installed correctly.

   ```
   $ yum search SDL2 #look for libraries and development headers should something like sdl2.0 and sdl2.0.0-dev
   ```
2. include SDL2 in sourcefile for example main.c

   ```
   #include "SDL2/SDL.h"
   ```
3. and make sure to link SDL2 library with the compiler flag -lSDL2

   ```
   $ clang main.c -lSDL2 -o programName
   ```

Answer (score 8):

```
sudo yum install SDL2-devel
```

You can search packages here: https://apps.fedoraproject.org/packages/SDL2-devel/