# /user/bin/ld: Cannot find SDL?

Tags: linux, gcc, sdl, fedora, ld

I am new to SDL I recently tried to run a SDL program on my Fedora machine and when I try to compile my program using the following command:

```
gcc -o displayimg displayimg.c -lSDL
```

I am getting the following error:

```
/var/bin/ld: cannot find LSDL
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have used the SDL2/SDL.h header as well. Any help would be appreciated. I am on Fedora 24.

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out. I was linking

```
-LSDL
```

instead of:

```
-LSD2
```

I followed this thread to help me out:

[How to install SDL2 library in Fedora 20](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26494683/how-to-install-sdl2-library-in-fedora-20)